# Invoking a web service - asmx - through a Microsoft Web API end point?

Tags: c#, web-services, asp.net-web-api, asmx, .net-4.5

I am using `Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2` and one of my end points has to internally invoke a legacy `asmx` web service.

Is this the correct way?

```
...................................................
WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(myWebServiceURL);

req.Method = "POST";
eq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

string postData = whateverDataNeedsToBePosted;

using ( Stream reqStream = req.GetRequestStream() )
      {
            reqStream.Write( new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes( postData ),
                              0, postData.Length );
            reqStream.Close();
       }
 WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
```

................................................

**UPDATE:** I do have a bunch of non-Microsoft technology web services (no asnx or svc). Is the above method good enough for those type of services?

Comment: Looks reasonable, but using auto-generated proxy as suggested by jebar8 would be much easier than constructing XML manually. If you decide to go this route please use proper XML API (like `XDocument`) to construct request/parse response.

Comment: Yes... Your super generic sample of POST will work for absolutely any kind of service that accepts POST HTTP requests (REST services, Web services/SOAP, regular HTML pages...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That will work, but you're making your life difficult :)

You can add a **Service Reference** to your project in Visual Studio and call methods in the ASMX service just like you would call methods in a referenced DLL. See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628649.aspx).

UPDATE:

Yes, your method for calling other services will work, but I would check to see if adding your other services as Service References to your project works first. The service reference feature works with all kinds of protocols (whether built with Microsoft technologies or not).